# How to find the surface area of revolution of an ellipsoid from ellipse rotating about y-axis

Tags: integration, conic-sections

Suppose the ellipse has equation $\frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$. 
I understand the way to obtain the surface area of the ellipsoid is to rotate the curve around y-axis and use surface of revolution.

But I'm wondering how to obtain this formula that I found on the internet $Area=2\pi b^{2}\left ( 1+\frac{a}{b} \frac{arcsin\varepsilon }{\varepsilon }\right )$ with with eccentricity $\varepsilon$ given by $\varepsilon =\sqrt{1-\left ( \frac{b}{a} \right )^{2}}$

Can anybody help prove it for me just from the ellipse equation above and surface of revolution? Thanks a lot:).

Comment: The formula applies to   'a > b'  (ie. only for prolate ellipsoid of revolution).

Comment: I think you meant $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. You have $a$ and $b$ in reversed roles in your top equation but in their usual roles in the eccentricity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I'm going to assume that the ellipse has the equation

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

since that's the more standard assumption. Yours has $a$ and $b$ reversed and I'm not sure if you meant it that way or if that was a typo on your part (I think it was a typo since your expression for the eccentricity matches the standard one). I'll also assume $a \ge b$. The case $b \ge a$ is handled similarly.

Now imagine that you rotate the ellipse around its long axis, that is, around the $x$ axis, and focus your attention on the strip that results from rotating a small arc of the ellipse, located at $(x,y)$ before the rotation. That elliptical arc has a length $ds$ that depends on its location, so it's a function of $(x,y)$. In fact, it's not hard to show that that arc-length is given by

$$ds = dx\,\sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$$

Anyway, the strip resulting from the rotation of that little elliptical arc has a circular shape and, therefore, an area approximately equal to

$$dA = 2\pi\,\mbox{radius} \times ds$$

and you can see from the figure that the radius is just $y$, so

$$dA = 2\pi\,y\,ds$$

Now, given the equation at the top, we find

$$\frac{2x\,dx}{a^2} + \frac{2y\,dy}{b^2} = 0$$

so

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{b^2}{a^2}\,\frac{x}{y}$$

and

$$ds = \frac{1}{a^2}\,\frac{dx}{y}\,\sqrt{b^4x^2 + a^4y^2}$$

As promised, $ds$ depends on $(x,y)$. Putting all of the above together, we find

$$dA = dx\,\frac{2\pi}{a^2}\,\sqrt{b^4x^2 + a^4y^2}$$

The area of the entire surface of revolution is then *twice* the integral of the above expression, from $x=0$ to $x=a$. *Twice* because we're integrating over only half the ellipse:

$$A = \frac{4\pi}{a^2}\int_{x\,=\,0}^{x\,=\,a} \sqrt{b^4x^2 + a^4y^2}\,dx$$

We still need to eliminate $y$, but that's easy. From the equation at the top, we find

$$y^2 = b^2 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}\,x^2$$

and then:

$$A = 4\pi\,\frac{b}{a}\int_{x\,=\,0}^{x\,=\,a} \sqrt{a^2 - (\frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2})\,x^2}\,dx$$

The quantity

$$\frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2}$$

is none other than the ellipse's eccentricity $\varepsilon$. So, finally, we have

$$A = 4\pi\,\frac{b}{a}\int_{x\,=\,0}^{x\,=\,a} \sqrt{a^2 - \varepsilon^2x^2}\,dx$$

Now use the parametrisation $x = a\,\sin\theta$ (Why $\sin$ instead of $\cos$? Because it makes the math easier down below. Shouldn't it be $\cos$, though? Not necessarily. Note that $x$ is now a dummy integration variable and we can choose any substitution we want) to get

$$A = 4\pi\,ab\,\int_{\theta\,=\,0}^{\theta\,=\,\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \varepsilon^2\sin^2\theta}\,\cos\theta\,d\theta$$

Next set $\sin\phi = \varepsilon\sin\theta$ so $\cos\phi\,d\phi = \varepsilon\cos\theta\,d\theta$ and

$$A = 4\pi\,\frac{ab}{\varepsilon}\,\int\cos^2\phi\,d\phi$$

(I omitted the integration limits but will get back to them below)

To integrate $\cos^2\phi$, we can use the fact that $\cos(2\phi) = \cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi = 2\cos^2\phi - 1$. Thus,

$$\cos^2\phi = \frac{1 + \cos(2\phi)}{2}$$

and

$$\int\cos^2\phi\,d\phi = \int\frac{1 + \cos(2\phi)}{2}\,d\phi =
\frac{\phi}{2} + \frac{\sin(2\phi)}{4}
$$

Now back to the integration limits. Note that $\theta = 0$ implies $\sin\phi = 0$, thus $\phi = 0$, and $\theta = \pi/2$ implies $\sin\phi = \varepsilon$, that is, $\phi = \arcsin(\varepsilon)$. Note also that $0 \le \varepsilon \le 1$ since $a \ge b$.

So then we get

$$A = 2\pi\,\frac{ab}{\varepsilon}\,(\phi + \frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2})\,\big|_{0}^{\arcsin(\varepsilon)} =
2\pi\,\frac{ab}{\varepsilon}\,\big[\,\arcsin(\varepsilon) + \frac{\sin(2\arcsin(\varepsilon))}{2}\,\big]
$$
Then, using $\sin(2\phi) = 2\sin\phi\cos\phi$, we find

$$A = 2\pi\,\frac{ab}{\varepsilon}\,\big(\,\arcsin(\varepsilon) + \varepsilon\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}\,\big)
$$

Finally, using the definition of the eccentricity, we get

$$A = 
2\pi\,\frac{ab}{\varepsilon}\,\big(\,\arcsin(\varepsilon) + \varepsilon\,\frac{b}{a}\,\big) = 
2\pi\,b^2\,\big(1 + \frac{a}{b}\,\frac{\arcsin(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon} \,\big)
$$

which is the expression you wanted to prove.

Comment: Incidentally, note that when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, $b$ becomes equal to $a$, we get a sphere rather than an ellipsoid, and we recover the surface area of a sphere of radius $a$, namely, $4\pi a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...start by expressing the ellipse in parametric form $$x=b\cos\theta, y=a\sin\theta$$

Then write down the standard integral for the surface area in parametric form. A trig sunstitution will solve it...

But it's a bit fiddly to type out in detail...